# Ubuntu scrollbars don't render on Cygwin X server

Tags: 12.04

I have an ubuntu 12.0.4 desktop.  I have a Win7 laptop running Cygwin. I can display windows from the Ubuntu box on the Win7 laptop using the Cygwin X server, but the window is somewhat "degraded".  Specifically, scrollbars are not rendering properly.  I've used Ubuntu before, but this is the first time I've seen these odd scrollbar popups that are used in 12.04.  I'm guessing the Cygwin X server is having trouble rendering that for some reason.  In the Cygwin view, I see the slightly thicker vertical bar, but when I hover the mouse over it, nothing happens.

I'd really prefer to get conventional scrollbars.  Can I configure Ubuntu 12.0.4 to do this, which might result in Cygwin being able to display them?

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer to this, at: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/879752/#msg_879752